# Field validation in custom commerce product's property

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I've customized a commerce product generated template adding a few fields via field mapping as shown in the commerce getting started guide.

Now I would like to add some validation to those fields but I faced a problem:

if I add a regex validation to the validation field (which works regularly). Next, when I updated this template using the update template job, I'm losing all the validation rule, because those rules were in Sitecore but not in Sitecore commerce.

Is there a way to avoid this problem? I wish to avoid some event-related validation method.

Comment: Unfortunately, no any other ways, except your.